# Filter taking 2 seconds on small adbodb recordset

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript, adodb

I have a small adodb recordset I am trying to filter. This one is 6 records for our test customer. 
For some reason the filter is taking 2 seconds to complete, and I am doing this around 30 times on my asp page. Thus, making my page really slow to load. The other recordset filters on this page are running fast.

I have tried setting different CursorLocations and CursorTypes..

Can anyone help me determine why this filter is so slow?

```
rsAvgPrice.Filter = "CommodityID = 13 AND CropYear = '12'"
```

Comment: Is this in a loop (outside of being called 30 times)?  Have you tested your database latency to see if it's high in general?

Comment: Correct, this is in a loop that is looping through another recordset. 

The weird thing is that there are 2 other recordsets being filtered by the same exact filter strings before and after this line, and those have no issues..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved this issue.

The issue was when I declare a record set the following way, the cursor type gets set as adOpenForwardOnly and the cursor location to adUseServer. These settings cannot be changed if you fill your recordset using command.Execute.

`Set cmd = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")`

`cmd.CommandType = adCmdText`

`cmd.CommandText = mySQL`

`cmd.CommandTimeout = 3000`

`cmd.ActiveConnection = cn`

`Set rs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")`

`Set rs = cmd.Execute`

`Set cmd = Nothing`

The way I resolved this was manually declaring a permanent recordset with its fields. Then I filled a temporary recordset using the command.execute. I then manually populated my declared recordset with the temporary recordset record by record. This allowed me to set the cursorlocation to adUseClient.
Thus speeding up the filter by leaps and bounds.

Comment: you could set [the cursorlocation of the connection object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681519%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Probably the whole query is executed again and only then the filter is being applied.

I would have one single loop over all the items, store the required data in local variables then have my own filter. Best efficiency, much better control.

For example, if you want the data filtered by those two fields, I would use Dictionary like this:

```vbs
Dim oCommodity_CropYear_Data, curKey
Dim curCommodityID, curCropYear, curData
Set oCommodity_CropYear_Data = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Do Until rsAvgPrice.EOF
    curCommodityID = rsAvgPrice("CommodityID")
    curCropYear = rsAvgPrice("CropYear")
    curKey = curCommodityID & "_" & curCropYear
    curData = "field1: " &  rsAvgPrice("somefield") & ", field 2: " & rsAvgPrice("other_field") & "<br />"
    oCommodity_CropYear_Data(curKey) = oCommodity_CropYear_Data(curKey) & curData
    rsAvgPrice.MoveNext
Loop
rsAvgPrice.Close
```

Then to extract the data in a  loop:

```vbs
For x=1 To 30
    For y=1 To 12
        curKey = x & "_" y
        If oCommodity_CropYear_Data.Exists(curKey) Then
            Response.Write("Data for Commodity " & x & " and CropYear " & y & ":<br />" & oCommodity_CropYear_Data(curKey)
        End If
    Next
Next
```

This is the general idea, hope you can use it for your actual needs.

Comment: I tried this and it did work, but it was a little harder to use and messy since my filter was inside of a recordset loop and I needed to use multiple fields from the rsAvgPrice recordset on different html elements.
Thank you for your suggestion!

Comment: If you can find a way to have the filter applied without re-running the whole query it would be better but otherwise, fear this is the only way.

Comment: I think the cursorlocation adUseServer was the ultimate issue here. Manually declaring my recordset so I could use an adUseClient cursor location fixed my problem. This prevented unwanted trips to the server on each filter.